# get a value of a specific row and column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, select

```
itemsets = [["26"], ["51", "28", "27"], ["50"], ["8"], ["81", "15"], ["10"], ["81"]]
support = [0.06421, 0.00123, 0.04112, 0.0112, 0.12097, 0.08123, 0.0021334]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["itemsets"]= itemsets
df["support"] = support
print(df)

    itemsets    support
0   [26]    0.064210
1   [51, 28, 27]    0.001230
2   [50]    0.041120
3   [8] 0.011200
4   [81, 15]    0.120970
5   [10]    0.081230
6   [81]    0.002133
```

For example I tried :

```
df.support.where(itemsets == ["26"])
```

I need to have `0.064210` as result, I would have a support of a given itemset.

Comment: Dont think this duplicate solves his problem as his column has iterables which can be tricky to select

Comment: it doesn't work i saw this duplicate before posting my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tuple` to perform your comparison, not `list`s.

Then, use `loc` and specify the column you want as below

```
df['itemsets'] = df.itemsets.transform(tuple)
df.loc[df.itemsets == ('26',), 'support']

0    0.06421
Name: support, dtype: float64
```

---

Notice you dont have to actually change your columns, e.g.

```
var = df.itemsets.transform(tuple)
val_to_compare = ['26']
df.loc[var == tuple(val_to_compare), 'support']
```

---

For any ordering

```
var = df.itemsets.transform(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))
val = ['26']
df.loc[var == tuple(sorted(val)), 'support']
```

Comment: but this transforms my data look ('26',) i don't need the coma because i need to use it in another algorithm

Comment: @AnisAmh you don't have to overwrite your column. Edited